# Lambda expression without declaration?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

An example for Lambda expressions from MSDN

```
delegate int del(int i);
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    del myDelegate = x => x * x;
    int j = myDelegate(5); //j = 25
}
```

Is it possible to do the same, without declaring the delegate?

Well since I think **declaring** is not the right word, I'll write the code as I would like to do it

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    del myDelegate = x => x * x;
    int j = myDelegate(5); //j = 25
}
```

**Why do I want to do that?**
I want to reduce complex if conditions into a single expression. But I don't want to *bloat* my class or add some kind of helper class / whatever since it won't be used in another scope.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6818709/3199781

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to do the same, without declaring the delegate?

No, it's not possible to create a lambda expression without first declaring a type. Delegates are like any other object in C#: it must have a well-defined type before you can assign it a value.

However, *you* may not need to declare the types *yourself*, because Microsoft has declared a ton of them for you. If one of the predefined delegate types works for you, feel free to use those.

For example, if you have a delegate that takes anywhere from 0 through 16 parameters, you can use one of the [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate types:

```
Action x = () => DoStuff();
Action<int> x = i => DoStuff(i);
Action<string, string, string> = (a,b,c) => DoStuff(a,b,c);
```

If you need to return a value, you can use one of the [`Func`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate types:

```
Func<int> x = () => 6;
Func<int, int> x = i => i * i;
Func<string, string, string, string> x = (a,b,c) => a.Replace(b, c);
```

etc.

There are tons more of them: every control event in Windows Forms or WPF uses a pre-defined delegate type, usually of `EventHandler` or `RoutedEventHandler` or some derivate. There are specialized version of `Func` such as [`Predicate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx) (though those largely pre-date LINQ and are mostly obsolete).

But, if for some odd reason none of the built-in delegate types works for you, then yes, you need to define your own before you can use it.

Comment: Well - excellent answer. Thanks for your explanation. Unfortunately I just can give a single +1 ;)

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for the `Func<*>` delegates:

```
Func<int, int> myDelegate = ...;
```