# How to box a function into an Object type?

Tags: c#

Is there a more concise way to add this function to the `object` list? I'd like to avoid having to assign into the intermediate `addFunc` variable.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<object> myObjects = new List<object>();

    //myObjects.Add(AddThings);

    Func<int, int, int> addFunc = AddThings;
    myObjects.Add(addFunc);
}

static int AddThings(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
```

Comment: Use from `GenericList<T>` for muti inputs or Cast `static` method.

Comment: If you have to use a `List<object>` i would question myself on the design of this. Something is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast it:

```
myObjects.Add((Func<int, int, int>) AddThings);
```

or

```
var myObjects = new List<object> { (Func<int, int, int>)AddThings };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define `delegate`:

```
delegate int AddThingsDelegate(int x, int y);
```

and then easily add it to your list like:

```
myObjects.Add(new AddThingsDelegate(AddThings));
```

For comparison between answers you can read: [What is the difference between Func and delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818656/what-is-the-difference-between-funcstring-string-and-delegate)