# Is there anything that you can do with 'delegate' but cannot do with either 'Action' or 'Func'?

Tags: c#, delegates

Apologizing in advance for the *newbie* kinda question (as I am one in C#):

While studying delegates, it seems to me that the combination of `Action` and `Func` covers the entire "functionality" of the `delegate` keyword.

In other words, there is nothing that you can do with the `delegate` keyword but cannot do with either `Action` or `Func`.

I've tried the following examples (which work fine):

```
Func<int,int,int,int> func = (x,y,z) => (x<<9)|(y<<6)|(z<<3);
Action<int,int,int> action = (x,y,z) => Console.WriteLine(x|y|z);
```

Am I wrong? If yes, then can you please provide a counterexample?

Comment: I would define Action and Func als Wrapper/helper classes that allow programmes Easy to use, and standardized delegates.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/11376657/1284902

Comment: Thanks @Tarec. I'd expect my question to be a duplicate of some previous post, but haven't been quite able to find one. Your link provides a partial answer to my question, but it kind of explains something that I already know. So basically I'm just trying to figure out whether once you have `Action` and `Func` it "covers the whole thing", or am I missing something here? Thanks again.

Comment: @barakmanos you are right, that answer doesn't explain the difference in purposes of using both. Please check this explanation, I hope it helps ;) http://stackoverflow.com/a/18741018/1284902

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to use a delegate other than `Action` or `Func` if you want to have:

1. More than 16 parameters to your method.
2. Any parameters be `ref` or `out` parameters.
3. A `params` parameter.
4. Optional arguments for any of your parameters.
5. Constraints on any of the generic arguments.  (Ensuring a parameter is any type that extends a type, that it has a parameterless constructor, that it is a value/reference type, etc.)
6. `unsafe` types used in the signature of the method, such as pointers as parameters.
7. Have a parameter that *isn't* contravariant, or a return type that's *not* covariant.  `Func` and `Action` both apply variance wherever possible, so if its important that your delegate *not* be variant, you would need your own.

Comment: `out`, `params` and optional arguments are actually three results of one common and more general impossibility with `Action`/`Func`: the ability to specify custom attributes.

Comment: You could add the case of `unsafe` types, i.e. a delegate type where some parameters, or the return value, are of pointer types. For example `public unsafe delegate string GetString(char* value);`.

Comment: Yet another use if you do not want the type parameters to be marked as co- or contravariant. Note that `System.EventHandler<TEventArgs>` is not contravariant (not "`in`") in `TEventArgs` because it can lead to problem with multicast delegates. So it is different from `Action<object, TEventArgs>` in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

You can create delegates that take `ref` or `out` parameters. You cannot define a `Func` or an `Action` that has `ref` or `out` parameters.

For example:

```
delegate void MyDelegate(ref string val);
```

Cannot be expressed as an `Action`.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents: With your own generic delegates you can apply [generic constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) which is not provided by `Func` or `Action`

```
delegate void MyDelegate<T>(T input) where T : struct;
```

Compiler will make sure `MyDelegate<T>` will always have value types as `T`, reference types are not allowed.