# Equivalent of typedef in c# for Action<> and/or Func<>

Tags: c#, types, delegates

After googling it doesn't look promising, but I'm wondering if there is some way of aliasing or typedef'ing when using `Action<T>` or `Func<in T, out TResult>` in C#?

I've already seen [Equivalent of typedef in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/161477/1548472), which says that within one compile scope you can use the `using` construct for some cases, but that doesn't seem to apply to `Action`'s and `Func`'s as far as I can tell.

The reason I want to do this is that I want an action to be used as a parameter to several functions, and if I, at some point in time, decide to change the action it's a lot of places to change both as parameter types and as variable types.

```
?typedef? MyAction  Action<int, int>;

public static SomeFunc(WindowClass window, int number, MyAction callbackAction) {
   ...
   SomeOtherFunc(callbackAction);
   ...
}

// In another file/class/...
private MyAction theCallback;

public static SomeOtherFunc(MyAction callbackAction) {
    theCallback = callbackAction;
}
```

Are there some construct to use, which can define the `MyAction` as indicated in the code segment?

Comment: typedef equivalent in C# is 'using'; using  MyAction = Action<int, int>;. but this has to be inside the namespace, and it is  only valid for that file. you will not be able to use it outside that file.

Comment: Your solution (the answer below) defining your own delegate type is fine. But there is no reason why you should not be able to make a [`using` alias directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) to `Action<,>`. Have you tried `using MyAction = System.Action<int, int>;`? Note that unless you have a `using System;` on a _higher_ level (not just the same `namespace` depth as your new `using` directive), you cannot leave out `System.` in `System.Action<...>`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: There is the very good reason, that I'm crossing compile scope as I'm crossing namespaces, which also is indicated in question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some more searching, it seems as though `delegate`'s comes to the rescue (see [Creating delegates manually vs using Action/Func delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4482613/1548472) and [A:
Custom delegate types vs Func and Action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18741018/1548472)). Please comment as to why this is not a solution or possible pitfalls.

With delegates I can rewrite the first line the given code example:

```
public delegate void MyAction(int aNumber, int anotherNumber);
// Keep the rest of the code example

// To call one can still use anonymous actions/func/...
SomeFunc(myWindow, 109, (int a, int b) => Console.Writeline);
```

Comment: This is a good solution. Be aware that different delegate types with the same signature do not automatically convert to each other. You can end up with a sea of delegate types that are incompatible with Func and Action.

Comment: Actually, historically, it is the other way round. Custom Delegates were there long before `Action` and `Func`. The main reason that `Action` and `Func` are there so prominently is exactly this sea of delegate types mentioned by usr

Answer (score 6):

```
using System;

namespace Example
{
    using MyAction = Action<int>;

    internal class Program
    {
    }

   private void DoSomething(MyAction action)
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Or `using MyAction = System.Action<int>; namespace Example { ... }`.

Comment: Is this allowed when crossing classes? or even across two namespaces?

Comment: I mentioned earlier on the comment, it is only allowed within a namespace within a file. you can use it with multiple classes in the same file. It will not work outside that file.

Comment: The `using` directive can be in the top of the file, before any occurrences of `namespace`. You just have to write `System.Action<...>` like in my first comment. The scope of the directive is the entire source file ("compilation unit") in that case. So you would need to repeat it in each file. I am not recommending it in particular, but it is possible.