# How do I declare a Func Delegate which returns a Func Delegate of the same type?

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I'd like to write a method which does some work and finally returns another method with the same signature as the original method. The idea is to handle a stream of bytes depending on the previous byte value sequentially without going into a recursion. By calling it like this:

```
MyDelegate executeMethod = handleFirstByte //What form should be MyDelegate?

foreach (Byte myByte in Bytes)
{
    executeMethod = executeMethod(myByte); //does stuff on byte and returns the method to handle the following byte
}
```

To handover the method I want to assign them to a Func delegate. But I ran into the problem that this results in a recursive declaration without termination...

```
Func<byte, Func<byte, <Func<byte, etc... >>>
```

I'm somehow lost here. How could I get around that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply declare a delegate type when the predefined `Func<...>` delegates aren't sufficient:

```
public delegate RecursiveFunc RecursiveFunc(byte input);
```

And in case you need it, you can use generics too:

```
public delegate RecursiveFunc<T> RecursiveFunc<T>(T input);
```

Comment: The signature of the method isn't know at compile time though.  He doesn't know that the parameter is a `Byte`.

Comment: @Servy In that case... `delegate RecursiveFunc<T> RecursiveFunc<T>(T input)`

Comment: excellent - works like a charm. In my case I know that it's going to be a Byte, but +1 for the generic version.